# MaVeN build takes, most of the times, wrong file

Tags: java, build, maven-3

I use the `org.apache.maven.plugins` `maven-assembly-plugin` version `2.2-beta-5` to build a *jar-with-dependencies*. One of the jars I include contains a `persistence.xml` file. The project that I build also has a `persistence.xml` file. The build finishes well.

The problem however is that most of the times the wrong `persistence.xml` file ends up in the *jar-with-dependencies*. If I, without changing anything, rebuild (and sometimes a few more times) then the correct `persistence.xml` is present.

I searched for a solution but I could not find a working example. How can I define in my `pom.xml` that I want my project's `persistence.xml` file in the *jar-with-dependencies* and not the one from the included jar?

My MaVeN version is *Apache Maven 3.6.3* and all builds are done with `mvn clean package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven-shade-plugin instead of mavenassembly-plugin to exclude the `persistence.xml` file from your dependencies

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>my:other:jar</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>persistence.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

More info on this approach in the [Apache Maven Shade Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I ran it a dozen times and everytime the shaded jar was executing.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment about time taken to build the executable without looking into your project.
By default Maven copies files from your **${project.basedir}/src/main/resources** location to the executable jar file. So If **persistence.xml** is not being included in fat jar then check your folder structure and check the location of your xml file.

Comment: It is always in my fat jar but not always from my `${project.basedir}`. It comes (most of the times) from a jar that is included in my fat jar. Since it is not always I assume that the copying is done in parallel. As a result it only takes the correct `persistence.xml` when there is some lag in one of the copy threads.